# why AudioManager.setMode(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION) interrupted background music for almost 2 seconds?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

in my android app, I had to set MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION to AudioManager while playing background music(.mp3), but as soon as I invoke setMode(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION), the background music was interrupted for almost 3 seconds？Of course being interrupted may be reasonable, but I think 3 seconds is too long, as I observed in other similar app at the same android device. any comment is appreciated.

Comment: it would be great to see the code you have written so far so that users can help you. Please could you include a code snippet.